# Flow Js - upload files as array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, flow-js

I am trying to use FlowJS angular plugin for a upload functionality and I need to tweak it a little.
I will have to files of all types

I am using ASP.NET MVC.

```
.config(['flowFactoryProvider', function (flowFactoryProvider) {
flowFactoryProvider.defaults = {
 target: '',
 permanentErrors: [500, 501],
 maxChunkRetries: 1,
 chunkRetryInterval: 5000,
 simultaneousUploads: 1
};
```

My input button

```
<input type="file" flow-btn />
```

My upload button

```
  <input type="button"  ng-click="uploadFiles($flow)">
```

And the function

```
 $scope.uploadme = function (flows) {
    flows.upload();
 });
```

My mvc controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        int fileSizeInBytes = file.ContentLength;
        MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
        file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
        byte[] data = target.ToArray();
        return "";
    }
```

This works fine, but when I upload multiple files, the controller is hit every time for a file. I need to find a way to send all files to the controller at once, some thing like

```
    public string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase[] file)
    {
    }
```

Any ways I can achieve this ?

Comment: Where is `input type file` from where you select files for upload ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad I have edited my question and added the select file button.

Comment: Have you tried see what data and how many files do you have in `Request.Files` collection?

Comment: I have two FlowFile array objects in my flows input parameter of uploadme  function. But flows.upload() calls the controller two times for each file one after the other.

Comment: I talked about `Request` object inside your mvc controller. It has property called `Files`. Try to see it and also you don't need to specify input parameter for your method. You should see all your uploaded files in `Request.Files` collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need something like `UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase[] file)` in your controller.

Just Create Controller

```
public string UploadFile()
{
  var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
  //httpRequest.Files.Count -number of files
  foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
  {
      var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
      using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(postedFile.InputStream))
      {
         //Your file
         string req = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binaryReader.ReadBytes(postedFile.ContentLength));

      }
}
}
```

Comment: This method works fine.. but is there any way to do this without formdata ? I need to send some other info in addition to the files in the same save action.. how can I achieve it.

Comment: If my answer helped you, then upvote it or accept it. And I see that you created a new question with the similar problem, so I think that this discussion in the comment section is not suitable now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864860/angularjs-ajax-mvc-file-multiple-upload-without-form-data. Do you have any inputs on my question ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `multiple` attribute to your `input`

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" flow-btn />
```

Comment: Please add more information to explain how this solves the problem