# AngularJS - ajax - MVC file multiple upload without form data

Tags: angularjs, ajax, model-view-controller, multipartform-data, flow-js

I am using Flow.JS http://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/ for file upload.

My requirement is such that I will have to send the following data all in **one save button click**

1. multiple files
2. two string values alongwith the files.

The following way works fine.

Upload ajax call

```
    $scope.UploadFiles = function (flows) {
    var data = new FormData();
    $.each(flows.files, function (i, flowfile) {
        data.append('file' + i, flowfile.file);
    });

    data.append('message', $scope.Subject);
    data.append('subject', $scope.Message);

 $.ajax({
        url: 'url\savedata',
        data: files,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST'
    }); 

}
```

And my MVC conroller

```
    public JsonResult Savedata()
    {

        var httpRequest = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if(httpRequest.Files.Count != 0)
        {
            var collection = 0;
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
              //manipulate file data
            }
        }

         var message = httpRequest.Forms['message'];
         var subject= httpRequest.Forms['subject'];

    }
```

All this works fine. I want to know if there is a better way to do this instead of using form data and possibly send all this data using a data model instead, since I need that for some MVC data validations.